The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system using Console App
This is my console app project. Previously it was running perfectly but last week it suddenly cannot run. When I try locally, it shows me this error: "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system".
What I tried:

Manually login to the Sharepoint Website using the same account and password. It is able to login and able to access to the folder that I wish to pull.

When I login to the Sharepoint Website using the same account and password, it does not request me to verify with phone call, sms etc. So I suspect this account is hasn't enabled MFA.


Note: This is not my account, this is my client's account, so I don't have much permission to check.
Below is my code:
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SharePointApiUrl")))
{
     string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SharePointPassword");
     string account = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SharePointAccount");
     var secret = new System.Security.SecureString();
     foreach (char c in password)
     {
           secret.AppendChar(c);
     }
     ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
     ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}


Were you able to solve this issue?
